# Is there object/class browsing in Visual Studio with C# while debugging/code tracing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, objectbrowser

So my idea is I want to see what an object's members or properties would return/change while I am debugging/tracing. There is Object Browser but it is only to show tree list of an object.

For example, let's say

```
var cacheDir = cotext.CacheDir;
```

But I want to change `.CacheDir` to `.ExternalCacheDir` while debugging to see what value would be returned to the variable.

```
var cacheDir = context.ExternalCacheDir;
```

Otherwise, I have to change it in editing mode and restart the whole debugging process. I think that we can do something like this in browser developer console or Jupyter notebook like CLI environment.

Answer (score 4):

With C# Keyboard settings you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - the immediate window. Or via the Command window type Immed.

In the Immediate Window you can do ad-hoc commands.

So in the debugger IDE you'd step over the line of code:

```
var cacheDir = cotext.CacheDir;
```

And now you want to  tweak it *just a once off*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Then paste:

```
cacheDir = cotext.ExternalCacheDir;
```

And press enter. You can always revert back in the immediate window, eg:

```
cacheDir = cotext.CacheDir;
```

If you just want to see the value of a variable you can do a <kbd>?</kbd> `cacheDir` to see the values. Give it a go :)

Comment: I see. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

While you're debugging, you can use Watch windows to watch variables and expressions.

```
Open a Watch window by selecting Debug > Windows > Watch > Watch 1, 
or pressing Ctrl+Alt+W > 1.

In the Watch window, select an empty row, and type variable or Expression

Continue debugging by selecting Debug > Step Into or pressing F11 as needed to advance.
The variable values in the Watch window change as you iterate through the for loop.
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to see variables values in VS. You can use the Watch Window, You can hover a variable and see a Data Tip, you can use the Immediate Window. You can also check OzCode that provides a HUD that shows the variable values without the need to open any Window, and provide a nice way to choose the properties that you like to present, and provides a google like search for variable name and values.
In the next version of OzCode (you can download a preview version of it) you can use OzCode Predict that also support VS Edit&Continue.